# Excel formula to take data only for Running periods

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two dates in an Excel file containing an inventory: start date and end date.

I want to be able to calculate sums for all the rows which don't have an end date set.

Comment: Could you add some sample data? What have you tried?

Comment: Use the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) like `=SUMIF(B:B, "<>End date", D:D)`.

Comment: After rereading your question, I believe my last comment was backwards. If you want to sum from another column when the End Date column is blank then it should be closer to `=SUMIF(B:B, "=", D:D)`.

Comment: Vendor          Start Date End Date                Volume
011 Encore 27-Feb-15 27-Mar-15        300,000
011 Etelix         11-Oct-14                                  480,000
011 Etelix         11-Oct-14         11-Nov-14        600,000
011 GTS        05-Mar-15                                  1,000,000
011 GTS        18-Dec-14         18-Jan-15        1,500,000
011 GTS        18-Jan-14         18-Feb-15        1,500,000 Now i want only 011 GTS's sum which is not having end date

Answer (score 0):

With a unique list of Vendors in ColumnG starting in G2 and assuming your first volume value is in E2, please try:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,B:B,G2,D:D,"")
```

copied down to suit.